# Fancybox background scroll with .open()

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have something of a wizard type workflow going with fancyboxes getting them to show and move from one to another works fine. I open the first one like so:

```
$('a.fancybox').fancybox();
```

In the html I simply have an anchor tag with the anchor id of what I want in the fancybox.

The problem arises when I move from the first box to the second box, which I open like so after a response from the server:

```
$.fancybox.open({ href: '#divIwantAsFancybox' });
```

This opens up the fancybox just fine, but in this instance the page in the background scrolls where the it did not on the first box. I have examined the inline css and html generated by fancybox and determined that the only difference of significant (probably) is that when using `.open()` the content I want is no longer rendered in a div with class fancybox-overlay. Manually moving the code into that div in the browser more or less renders that fancybox unusable. I'm at a loss here and have no idea how to instruct fancybox to open the second box while not scrolling the background.

PS: I have tried the css hack of setting `overflow: hidden` in beforeShow and afterClose, and while that works for me on the browser it does not have the desired effect on a mobile browser. For the purpose of this question I'd like to stick to a web solution for now, but potentially avoid that hack since I know it won't work for me on mobile browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a better response, you may also need to show your html: how your anchors and target divs are populated, etc. Maybe you just need to use the same type of anchor inside a fancybox as the one, which triggered the first fancybox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several hours of digging, I found some other people using the `overflow: hidden` trick but on the body instead of one of the fancybox divs. Whenver you call `$.fancybox()` or `$.fancybox.open()`, you can pass in the callback functions like so:

```
$.fancybox({ beforeShow: function() { 
    $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
}, afterClose: function() {
    $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
}});
```

However, if anyone knows of a better way to handle this, please feel free to add your two cents, as this is, in my opinion, a bug with fancybox. I would expect calling `$.fancybox.open()` to behave the same way referencing an anchor with `$('a.fancybox').fancybox()` would.